Can't import `torch` package
I tried to run a simple Neural Network model using Pytorch with the speed up of my GPU. I have installed CUDA Toolkit 12.6, cuDNN v8.9.7 for CUDA 12.x, as well as using this pip command pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu124 to install torch packages.
However, when I try to run this code under conda environment, it can't even import torch.
import torch

print(torch.cuda.is_available())
print(torch.cuda.get_device_name(0))

What is the error, and how to solve it?


Thank you, Talonmies. It worked for me now.
